# String literal in Select statement appears as a series of + signs in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT YEAR(SalesDate) AS Year, COUNT(VehicleID) AS VehicleCount 
FROM CarsSales GROUP BY Year(SalesDate)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM(SalesDate) FROM CarCount;
```

Which returns the following result set. I need the + signs to say "Total" but I am confused as to why it isn't printing out like I expected it to.

```
Year            VehicleCount
2000            1228
2001            4768
2002            14004
++++++++++++++  20000
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a DB2 database handy, but I'm guessing that your problem is that you are trying to mix integer data ( YEAR(SalesDate) ) with character data (the literal 'Total'), and that the + signs are DB2's way of displaying 'NaN'.

Try changing YEAR(SalesDate) to CHAR(YEAR(SalesDate)) so that all entries in the first column will be CHAR types.

Comment: This is the case - getting `+` signs is basically it saying 'sorry, unexpected (non-fatal) data encountered.  Please try again'.  You can get this for out-of-range errors, too (like `Total` records that sum up too many small values....).